# Excel - How to return if value x is in array part of column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So the header is probably wrongly worded, but struggling a bit with describing the problem in a sentence.

I have a list as so:

[image]

How do I make a formula, that finds for any A, if any row with A has a X+Y any where, and not just in the current row.

Comment: You just want to know if such a combination excists? `A` and `X+Y`? In that case you could use `Countifs()` for example

Comment: Well, technically, I want in descending order something like, is there X+Y, then X else  Y.
But how would you use countif?

Comment: Something like so: `IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,"A",$B$2:$B$12,"X+Y")>0,"X","Y")`?

Comment: Ahh, sorry wasn't precise enough.
What I want is an additional coloumn, that states if the current unique ID for this row, has any row with X+Y, if not then X else Y.
i.e. I need it for each array, without knowing what unique ID I have at the moment.

So I need it so it works for A, B and C etc.

Comment: Still, why cant you just swap the hardcoded `"A"` for a cell reference? Like: `IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,A2,$B$2:$B$12,"X+Y")>0,"X","Y")` and drag that down in column C

Answer (score 1):

Nut sure I get your question right (also the title says something else than the text)

Count "X+Y"

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$12,"A",$B$1:$B$12,"X+Y")
```

Count "X+Y" for any ID. Paste in C2 and drag down

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$12,A2,$B$1:$B$12,"X+Y")
```

Count any kind of "X" occurence

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$12,"A",$B$1:$B$12,"X*")
```

Answer (score 1):

If i get it correct you want to count how many times the combination **A** & **X+Y** appears in your data?

Import the below formula in cell D2:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,"A",$B$2:$B$12,"X+Y")
```

Results:

[image]